# How to put this JSON into a room sql

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

**Hello guys, help solve the problem with the room, during the week I can not load data from the sub-class, when I get data with the help of retrofit there are no problems, but I can not find the solution to write the data to the comet. Used @Relation, @Embedded and all without success. I will be very grateful for any help. Izvestenie that if it is written is not clear, Google used translator**

```
  "code": 200,
  "sucsses": true,
  "data": {
    "booking_info": [
    {
    "_id": "5af2d48bc09d261ba4e20bf0",
      "imageBooking": [

    ],
    "nameBooking": "nameBooking",
    "descriptionBooking": "descriptionbooking fqwfqwfqwf qwfqwfqwfqwfqwf",
    "taskBooking": "Привезти песок",
    "priceBooking": null,
    "rateBooking": null,
    "coordinateBooking": {
      "latitudeBooking": 234345444,
      "longitudeBooking": 325253525
    },
    "clockWork": null,
    "user_id": "5ae5ec8da8f2a90b04b1f715"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5af45fa836ee831b540849f1",
    "imageBooking": [

    ],
    "nameBooking": "nameBooking",
    "descriptionBooking": "descriptionbooking fqwfqwfqwf qwfqwfqwfqwfqwf",
    "taskBooking": "Привезти песок",
    "priceBooking": null,
    "rateBooking": null,
    "coordinateBooking": {
      "latitudeBooking": 234345444,
      "longitudeBooking": 325253525
    },
    "clockWork": null,
    "user_id": "5ae5ec8da8f2a90b04b1f715"
  },
```

**data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "booking")
data class BookingModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var code: Int = 0,
    var sucsses: Boolean = true,
    @Ignore
    var data: BookingModel?,
   @TypeConverters(GithubTypeConverters::class)
    var booking_info: List<BookingModel>?

) {
    constructor() : this(0, 0, true, null, null)
}




 @TypeConverter
fun fromCountryLangList(countryLang: List<BookingModel>?): String? {
    if (countryLang == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<BookingModel>>() {

    }.type
    return gson.toJson(countryLang, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toCountryLangList(countryLangString: String?): List<BookingModel>? {
    if (countryLangString == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<BookingModel>>() {

    }.type
    return gson.fromJson<List<BookingModel>>(countryLangString, type)
}



 @Database(
            entities = [
            BookingModel::class],
            version = 1,
           exportSchema = false
 )
 @TypeConverters(GithubTypeConverters::class)
 abstract class HelpCarDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
  abstract fun daoService(): DaoService
}
```

Comment: When do you build the room database?, can you share logs and the room buider block?

Comment: In the journal there is nothing to be found, just an empty table booking_info